# Kotlin complains about incorrect type despite lambda matching the signature

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I have some code that, according to IntelliJ's inspection, expects `Function< in (Mutable)List<String!>!, out Int!>!`, but is provided `(List<String>) -> Int`. To my knowledge, the latter is a valid signature for the former.

The code in question:

```
val longest = HashMap<String, List<String>>()
        .apply {
            this["aal"] = listOf("ala", "aal", "laa")
            this["eilv"] = listOf("evil", "live")
            this["aaa"] = listOf("aaa", "aaa", "aaa")
        }
        .values
        .stream()
        .collect(groupingBy({ list: List<String> -> list.size },
                Supplier { TreeMap<Int, List<List<String>>>() },
                toList()))
        .lastEntry()
        .value
```

What I wanted to do is to to have `longest` variable that will store all the internal `List`s of the created `HashMap` that have the greatest length.

In order to do so, I wanted to `collect` all of those *entries* by *grouping* them into a `TreeMap` (because of it having ordered entries by `key`), where `key` would be the inner lists' `size`s (thus the `lastEntry().value` would yield a `List` of `List`s with the greatest sizes).

Why is my `{ list: List<String> -> list.size }` not conforming to expected `classifier`? What are the differences between these types? How can I convert said lambda to satisfy the requiremenets of the library?

EDIT:

The full error message is:

> ```
> Type inference failed: fun <T : Any!, K : Any!, D : Any!, A : Any!, M : (Mutable)Map<K!, D!>!> groupingBy(p0: Function<in T!, out K!>!, p1: Supplier<M!>!, p2: Collector<in T!, A!, D!>!): Collector<T!, *, M!>!
> cannot be applied to
> ((List<String>) -> Int,Supplier<TreeMap<Int, List<List<String>>>!>,Collector<List<String>!, *, (Mutable)List<List<String>!>!>!)
> ```

However, when I change this:

```
 .collect(groupingBy({ list: List<String> -> list.size },
          Supplier { TreeMap<Int, List<List<String>>>() },
          toList()))
```

to this:

```
.collect(groupingBy({ list: List<String> -> list.size },
         { TreeMap<Int, List<List<String>>>() },
         toList()))
```

fixes the problem. Why is that? Why specifying the `Supplier` name alters the bahaviour in such a way that the error message complains about the mapping function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation detail of how Kotlin currently provides [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions): it sees that `groupingBy` has two parameters with SAM types (`Function` and `Supplier`) and creates a synthetic method which replaces *both* of them by Kotlin function types. So you can only pass two Kotlin functions (as in your last example) or a `Function` and a `Supplier`:

```
.collect(groupingBy(Function { list: List<String> -> list.size },
    Supplier { TreeMap<Int, List<List<String>>>() },
    toList()))
```

(may need to import `java.util.function.Function` and possibly specify type parameters)